# Method not allowed in Index

Tags: ajax, laravel

please help with my problem
I cannot make Ajax call from my main view in laravel. I am receiving **FAIL: Method Not Allowed STATUS: error**, the problem does not occur on other pages. I am including CSRF in header in ajaxsetup:
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

//SECURE OUR AJAX CALLS:
`var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN } });`

and I am using: 
         `$.post("test", function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("FAIL: "+error+" STATUS: "+status);
});`
Here is routes.php: 
        `Route::post('test', 'TestController@test');`

Here is my controller:
        `public function test(Request $request){ echo 123; die(); }`

thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe your routes are cached? Try `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: No, I did not cache routes. I connected with putty and ran `php artisan cache:clear` inside my project folder, but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

it would seem you have an error in your php since what you get returned is PHP failing

Check the chrome/firefox/safari network console rather than `console.log()` this way you can see the exact line PHP fails

Comment: "Method not allowed" seems like a Laravel error, anyhow he said that other API methods do work.

Comment: in PHP I have empty function: <br>`public function test(Request $request){ echo 123; die(); }`, I imlemented (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website) this language pack, maybe it is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with redirection: mydomain.com does not work, but mydomain.com/en/ this works, now will try to automatically redirect page to correct destination. Thanks

Comment: @timenomad well they might call different controllers